# How to run this api for every team from my database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, api

I am using this API to get user emails for every member of a team. The teams are taken from a mongo database. I want to get this API to run for every team in the database and to return a list of emails for every member of every team. Right now, the API is only retrieving emails for members of the first team in the database.

```
with open('config/config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)
API_KEY = config['API_KEY'] # loads API key

# Database info
client = MongoClient(config['HOST'], config['PORT'])
db = client[config['DATABASE']]
teams = list(db.teams.find())  # gets all the teams from the database

def list_users():
  url = 'https://api.pagerduty.com/users'
  headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2',
    'Authorization': 'Token token={token}'.format(token=API_KEY)
  }
  result = []
  for team in teams:
    payload = {
        'team_ids[]': team['team_id'],
        'limit': 100,
        'offset': 0
    }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)

    users = r.json()['users']
    emails = []
    # loops for each user and retrieves their email
    for user in users:
      if r.status_code == 200:
        emails.append(user['email'])
      else:
        return None
    return emails
  return result
```

How can I get this to run for every team from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're prematurely returning from your loop on teams. If you collect the emails in the result list instead, your issue is resolved.

```python
def list_users():
    url = 'https://api.pagerduty.com/users'
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.pagerduty+json;version=2',
        'Authorization': 'Token token={token}'.format(token=API_KEY)
    }
    result = []
    for team in teams:
        payload = {
            'team_ids[]': team['team_id'],
            'limit': 100,
            'offset': 0
        }
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)

        users = r.json()['users']
        emails = []
        # loops for each user and retrieves their email
        for user in users:
            if r.status_code == 200:
                emails.append(user['email'])
        result.append(emails)
    return result
```